# Trying to push any C/C++ type to the Lua stack using C API with templates

Tags: c++, c, templates, lua

Lua has many functions that you can use to push values onto the stack.  I attempted to use a template to accomplish this, but I seem to be running into some problems. I understand the code is created from the template when it is used.  **So, I am guessing the problem is that the type that is used does not match an argument type of a Lua function that I could possibly use.**  Is there a way around this?  I am somewhat new to C++, so if anyone can find the technique name or the process to fix this problem that would be awesome!  I couldn't find anything about solving this with templates online. I am using enums to avoid directly checking the type with C++, because apparently it's a little complicated and/or not guaranteed to work. Thanks in advance!

```
enum class LuaType {
    nil = LUA_TNIL, boolean = LUA_TBOOLEAN, lightUserData = LUA_TLIGHTUSERDATA,
    number = LUA_TNUMBER, string = LUA_TSTRING, table = LUA_TTABLE, function = LUA_TFUNCTION,
    userdata = LUA_TUSERDATA, thread = LUA_TTHREAD, numtags = LUA_NUMTAGS
};

template<typename T>
    void createGlobalVariable(const char* name, LuaType type, T value = NULL) {

        switch (type) {

        case LuaType::nil:
            lua_pushnil(this->state.get());
            break;
        case LuaType::boolean:
            lua_pushboolean(this->state.get(), value);
            break;
        case LuaType::number:
            lua_pushnumber(this->state.get(), value);
            break;
        case LuaType::string:
            lua_pushstring(this->state.get(), value);
            break;
        case LuaType::table:
            lua_newtable(this->state.get());
            break;

        }

        lua_setglobal(this->state.get(), name);
    }
```

**Edit:** This is what it looks like when overloaded, but I wish there was a better way to do it.

```
void createGlobalVariable(const char* name, double value) {
    lua_pushnumber(this->state.get(), value);
    lua_setglobal(this->state.get(), name);
}

void createGlobalVariable(const char* name, int value) {
    lua_pushinteger(this->state.get(), value);
    lua_setglobal(this->state.get(), name);
}

void createGlobalVariable(const char* name, const char* value) {
    lua_pushstring(this->state.get(), value);
    lua_setglobal(this->state.get(), name);
}

void createGlobalVariable(const char* name, void* value) {
    lua_pushlightuserdata(this->state.get(), value);
    lua_setglobal(this->state.get(), name);
}

void createGlobalVariable(const char* name, bool value) {
    lua_pushboolean(this->state.get(), value);
    lua_setglobal(this->state.get(), name);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to say what are the problems you are running into

Comment: @immibis I am trying run a different Lua function based on the type that is given in the C++ function.  The compiler is trying to evaluate lua_pushstring() even though I am trying to get it to only evaluate lua_pushboolean().  Is there a way to do this in one function without having to write many functions?

Comment: I don't believe there is. Your options are plain old function overloading, or template specialization, and either way you have to write a separate function for every type.

Comment: (Aside: your declaration lets me do something like `createGlobalVariable("test", LuaType::string, 42);` - what does that even *mean*?)

Comment: I did the function overloading, but it just feels clunky and feels like there should be a better way :P.

Comment: The reason the second argument is an enum because I wanted to avoid manually type checking variables in C++; apparently it's challenging and the obvious answer to check types in C++ isn't really reliable.